# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Cookie Persistence

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

My Startup.cs has these entries

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie();
```

The consent cookie seems to work properly. It shows as below and persists properly

> .AspNet.Consent |  Expiry: 2021-02-19T23:22:24.000Z

However the Identity cookie set when you login and choose to persist is not working as intended. The cookie is set

> .AspNetCore.Identity.Application | Expiry: 2020-04-06T09:32:38.998Z

But then when returning to the site the user is not logged in.
It's a bit odd, it seems to work for about 15 mins or so, then when you go back you don't get logged back in.

//edit

Another addition to this. I have noticed that even when signed in and using the application. If you go idle for about 10 - 15 minutes without closing the browser, you are logged out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually caused by the shared host using Plesk. It had a setting where the application pool was terminated when idle for 10 mins. I had that changed to suspended and it has solved this issue.